# How to change Text Color in TextButton(FlatButton (deprecated))?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning FLutter and started with the deprecated version of TextButton i.e FlatButton the colors seems to work but in TextButton version textColor is not working.

Here's the code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            resultPhrase,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Restart Quiz!',),
            textColor:Colors.blue,
            onPressed: resetHandler,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried Style with foreground colors and it didnt work..am i missing something?
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)
Tried the above through another thread and didnt work.
Is there any way to find most of the descriptions of parameters like they have in Tailwind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `style` on  `TextButton`.

```dart
TextButton(
  child: Text('Restart Quiz!',),  
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    textStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blue,
    )
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the "style" of the button like this.

```
TextButton(
     style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.white, //for background color backgroundColor:
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            child: const Text('Gradient'),
          ),)
```